# ¿Cómo añadir una tarjeta/tarea con miembro/s en Trello desde su API?

Tags: trello

Estoy haciendo uso de la API de Trello para crear tableros, listas y tarjetas o tareas, no obstante, ocurre un problema al intentar crear esa tarjeta y asignarle un miembro.

He seguido exactamente lo que dice la documentación: [Documentación oficial de la API de Trello - Sección de tarjetas](https://developers.trello.com/reference#cardsid-1)

```
function crearTarjeta($nombre, $idLista, $fecha, $finalizada, $notas)
{
    //Esta función tiene una excepción, ya que si bien debe enviarse por POST, Trello espera que los parametros se especifiquen en la url
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077599/creating-a-card-via-trello-fails-with-a-400-response
    global $apikey, $oauth;
    $nombre = urlencode($nombre);
    $notas = urlencode($notas);
    if(!empty($fecha))
        $url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards?key=$apikey&token=$oauth&name=$nombre&idList=$idLista&due=$fecha&dueComplete=$finalizada&desc=$notas&idMembers=ACAMIID";
    else
        $url = "https://api.trello.com/1/cards?key=$apikey&token=$oauth&name=$nombre&idList=$idLista&dueComplete=$finalizada&desc=$notas&idMembers=ACAMIID";
    $metodo = "POST";
    $tarea = request($url, $metodo, NULL);
    return $tarea;
}
```

Entonces, cuando quito el parámetro `idMembers` de la función `crearTarjeta` todo funciona correctamente, pero cuando lo agrego me muestra el siguiente error:

> {"message":"Invalid objectId","error":"ERROR"}

Si ven la documentación dice que es un valor del tipo `string` y que, en caso de haber más de uno deben estar separados con coma entre ellos, a pesar de esto he intentado añadir una coma / un punto y coma al final para probar y el error persiste.

¿Tienen idea de como proceder de forma correcta para poder añadir los miembros?

También aclaro que he probado añadir el valor (ID de miembro) entre comillas dobles codificadas -> **%22ACAMIID%22**

Comment: **El ID de usuario es un número**. Efectivamente se pasa como cadena, pero es un número. Si tu username es ACAMIID puedes obtener tu ID desde el navegador abriendo [https://api.trello.com/1/members/ACAMIID](https://api.trello.com/1/members/ACAMIID)